# Python function that acts as a macro

Tags: python, urllib

I have a very simple request. I want to write a python function that can download multiple csv files from a website and save them in a specified location. I have found how to simply download a csv file, but want to create a function that can do this multiple times so a different file is downloaded each iteration.

```
import urllib
url = "http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/File.csv"
get = urllib.urlretrieve(url , "X:\Data\File.csv")
get
```

I want to change "File" in the code above to say "X", then "Y", "Z" etc.

Can someone please show me how this is done.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This kind of question seems to me that you have no programming experience whatsoever. Maybe you should try easier examples first...

Comment: Correct I am not a programmer. I just want to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try easier examples first. There are a lot of tutorials out there. You should look for string handling and string concatenation.

Comment: Are the list of files similar ?? Like in series or repitition

Comment: Yes the urls all have the same beginning i.e. "http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/" and I just want to change the bit at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. First make a list of file names , find its length, then run a loop to get your data. below is the code:-

```
A = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
length = len(A)
for i in range (0,length):
    u = "http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/"
    r = A[i]
    url = u + r + ".csv"
    temp = "X:\Data\" + r + ".csv"
    get = urllib.urlretrieve(url , temp)
    get
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: a.) you might as well use `for a in A` there. b.) Don't ever concatenate paths/urls like that. Never do that. You're gonna shoot yourself in the foot big time with this. This is where security vulnerabilities come from.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do something like that you should probably invest the time to actually learn even the simplest basics of programming languages. Anyway,

```
for f in files:
  s = 'Hi, ' + f
  print s
```

Should give you some hint what you need to do. However, beware that you can't simply concatenate paths like that because that's unsafe. You'll have to use  [urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) and [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join%20os.path.join)